# Hot Key for a VS 2008 Macro?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

I've written a little macro for my VS 2008 IDE, and I want to associate it with a hot key.  From what I can see, the keyboard shortcuts in the Tools/Options only allow you to select from the predefined actions.

Is there any way to associate a hot key with a user-defined macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Assigning Shortcut Keys to a Macro](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/macroshortcutkey.html) it is pretty clear that you should be able to do this.

Comment: Doh, of course it was there... dunno why I didn't see it before!
Thanks!